# Is it possibile using Artisan command on web server?

Tags: laravel

I would like to ask if is possible using following command on webserver.

```
 public function addCache() {

        \Artisan::call('config:cache');


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, connect to your web server with terminal, most of the time you will need to ssh into it, and then navigate to the project root folder, then run the `php artisan` command as what you typically do

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route with artisan call

```
Route::get('/clear', function () {
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have terminal on your host or server, you can define a route and define this artisan call inside that.

```
Route::get('cache-config',function(){
    \Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return back();
});
```

Or you can use [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/babak271/shared-host-artisan) for this artisan commands and some other useful commands.